# Userform with if statement

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a user form that has multiple combo boxes.
I then have textboxes that contain vlookups that are working and one textbox that requires an "IF" statement.

The statement will run after a weight is entered into Weighttb.

Then I need to calculate a price.

- if the weight is less than 35kg then calculate 3.98 + (weight - 35) *0.2
  else the price is 3.98
- however if the postcode selected is "BT" the calculation will be 12.88 + (weight -30) * 0.6

```vb
Private Sub Weighttb_Change()

If PostCodecb = "BT" Then
    UKMtb = 12.88 + (Weighttb - 30) * 0.6

ElseIf Weighttb <= "35" Then
    UKMtb = 3.98 + (Weighttb - 35) * 0.2

Else
    UKMtb = "3.98"

End If
End Sub
```

The calculation does not seem correct.

Comment: How did you define the variable `Weighttb`? It should be numeric, same for `"35"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more info about the code, I see two things that may be influencing the "if" statement:

- It seems that if PostCodecb = "BT", then it does not matter the value of Weighttb, right? But in that case, just for precaution, declare it in the second statement.
- The 35 is an integer, but with the quotation marks that you are using, it transforms into a string. This goes as well for the third statement, in case you need UKMtb for further calculations.

Try using something like:

```
Private Sub Weighttb_Change()
    If PostCodecb = "BT" Then
        UKMtb = 12.88 + (Weighttb - 30) * 0.6
    ElseIf Weighttb <= 35 and PostCodecb <> "BT" Then
        UKMtb = 3.98 + (Weighttb - 35) * 0.2
    Else
        UKMtb = 3.98
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps! If not, give me more details and I'll try to find other problems.

Mike

Comment: Amazing thank you so much, the figures are matching another version of this created just using calculations in a spreadsheet so good sign :)